# Programmatically download a file accessed via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vba, ms-access

I have a website that hosts reports. I can download the report as a file if I click a java script encoded button. I'd like to use VBA to download the file programmatically but have no idea if it's even possible let alone where to start looking.

I hear you can embed java script into HTML. Would it be possible to call the website using a customized URL that incorporates the websites java script?

I also thought about downloading the page and crafting it so that when it's called locally as a file it will automatically run the javascript and prompt the download from the external server.

The URL is

```
https://my.workflowmax.com/reports/view.aspx?id=12345
```

The button in question has this: I have no idea what it means.

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageContent$btn1_Option1','')
```

Here is the full html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html class=" ext-strict" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>
    WorkflowMax | Inventory Report
</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/ext-all.css"><link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/HttpCombiner-v3_2_3_148.css"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/blue.css"><!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/IE7.css" /><![endif]--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/print.css" media="print"></head>
<body class="maxbody  ext-gecko ext-gecko3">

<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/workflowmax.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/20100518-lib.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/ext-prototype-adapter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/ext-all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/HttpCombiner-v3_2_3_148.js"></script>


    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="view.aspx?id=1549031" id="aspnetForm" autocomplete="off">
<div>
<input name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="__VIEWSTATE_GUID" id="__VIEWSTATE_GUID" value="3ff79129-c11a-4377-9585-dc9af902c872" type="hidden">
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="
__VIEWSTATE" value="" type="hidden">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/WorkFlowMax_003.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/WorkFlowMax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/WorkFlowMax_002.js"></script>
<script text/javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageContent$btn1_Option1','')""></script>


        <div class="module-report pagetype-reportview">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="MaxBanner">

                    <div class="userlabel">John Doe | ExampleCompany</div>

                    <div id="ext-gen3" class="search">
                        <div style="width: 319px;" id="ext-gen4" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap"><input style="width: 318px;" autocomplete="off" name="search_field" id="search_field" class="SearchTextBox x-form-text x-form-field" type="text"><img style="display: none;" id="ext-gen5" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/s.gif" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger"></div> 
                            <a href="javascript:GoSearch();" id="btnSearch" class="SearchButton2">
                                <span>GO</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>    

                </div>
<!--                
                <div class="spacer">
                </div>
-->                

                <div class="menu2">
                    <ul class="menu-nav" id="nav-left"><li class="menu-spacer " style="width:20px; z-index: 1;"></li><li id="my-menu-c2" class="top" style="z-index:1;"><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/my/overview.aspx">My Max</a><div class="callout" id="my-menu-c2"><div class="menu-column1"><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/my/overview.aspx">Overview</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/my/timesheet.aspx?filter=">Time Sheet</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/my/preferences.aspx">Preferences</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/portal/default.aspx">Portal</a></li></ul></div><div class="menu-column2"><h1>Enter Time</h1><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/my/timesheet.aspx?filter=">Daily</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/my/timesheet.aspx?filter=&amp;tab=weekly">Weekly</a></li></ul></div></div></li><li class="top" style="z-index:1;"><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/client/clientlist.aspx">Clients</a><div class="callout"><div class="menu-column1"><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/client/clientlist.aspx">Client Manager</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/client/clientedit.aspx">New Client</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/client/contactlist.aspx">Contact Manager</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/client/supplierlist.aspx">Supplier Manager</a></li></ul></div></div></li><li class="top" style="z-index:1;"><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/joblist.aspx">Jobs</a><div class="callout"><div class="menu-column1"><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/joblist.aspx">Job Manager</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/jobedit.aspx">New Job</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/tasklist.aspx">Task Manager</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/collaboration.aspx">Collaboration Manager</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/jobschedule.aspx">Job Schedule</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/resourceschedule.aspx">Staff Schedule</a></li></ul></div></div></li><li class="top" style="z-index:1;"><a href="#">Financial</a><div class="callout"><div class="menu-column1"><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/financial/quotelist.aspx">Quote Manager</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/financial/quoteedit.aspx?type=2">New Estimate</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/financial/quoteedit.aspx?type=1">New Quote</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/financial/invoicelist.aspx">Invoice Manager</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/common/option.aspx?id=0&amp;pagetype=131">New Progress Invoice</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/common/option.aspx?id=0&amp;pagetype=130">New Invoice</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/financial/purchaseorderlist.aspx">Purchase Order Manager</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/financial/timesheet.aspx">Time Sheets</a></li></ul></div></div></li><li id="report-menu" class="top selected" style="z-index:1;"><a href="#">Reports</a><div class="callout" id="report-menu"><div class="menu-column1"><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/common/option.aspx?id=0&amp;pagetype=139">Financial Reports</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/reports/my.aspx">My Reports</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/reports/builder.aspx">Report Builder</a></li></ul></div><div class="menu-column2"><h1>Favourites</h1><ul><li><span>There are no favourite reports selected.</span></li></ul></div></div></li><li id="admin-menu-c2" class="top" style="z-index:1;"><a href="#">Admin</a><div class="callout" id="admin-menu-c2"><div class="menu-column1"><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/clienttypelist.aspx">Client Type</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/costlist.aspx">Cost</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/customfieldlist.aspx">Custom Fields</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/customtemplatelist.aspx">Custom Templates</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/documentmanagement.aspx">Document Management</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/jobtypelist.aspx">Job Category</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/jobstatelist.aspx">Job State</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/jobtemplatelist.aspx">Job Template</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/notification.aspx">Notification</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/personalise.aspx">Personalise</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/preferences.aspx">Preferences</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/resourcelist.aspx">Staff</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/tasklist.aspx">Task</a></li></ul></div><div class="menu-column2"><h1>Interfaces</h1><ul><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/connectors.aspx">Connectors</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/ipayroll.aspx">iPayroll</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/kashflow.aspx">KashFlow</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/saasu.aspx">Saasu</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/xero2.aspx">Xero</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/common/option.aspx?id=0&amp;pagetype=149">Export</a></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/common/option.aspx?id=0&amp;pagetype=150">Import</a></li></ul></div></div></li><li class="menu-spacer-left " style="width:20px; z-index: 1;"></li></ul><ul class="menu-nav" id="nav-right"><li class="menu-spacer right" style="width:20px; z-index: 1;"></li><li id="menu-timeclock" class="top timeclock" style="z-index:1;"><a href="#" onclick="WorkflowMax.UI.TimerManager.toggle();"> </a></li><div id="timer-dropdown" class="hidden"></div><li class="top" style="z-index:1;"><a href="#">Help</a><div class="callout"><div class="menu-column1"><ul><li><a href="http://support.workflowmax.com/home" target="_blank">Need Help?</a></li><li><a href="http://support.workflowmax.com/categories/10336" target="_blank">Video Tutorials</a></li><li><a href="http://events.workflowmax.com/upcoming-courses/locations/online" target="_blank">Webinars and Training</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/max/contact.aspx">Contact Support</a></li><li><a href="javascript:WorkflowMax.UI.Support.invite();">Invite Support?</a></li><li class="menu-break"><div class="menu-break"> </div></li><li><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/admin/subscription.aspx">My Subscription</a></li></ul></div></div></li><li class="top" style="z-index:1;"><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/logout.aspx">Logout</a></li></ul>
                </div>

                <div class="MaxPageInfo">
                    <div class="pageinfopath"><a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/reports/my.aspx">My Reports</a><span>›</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div><span class="pageinfotitle">Inventory Report</span>
                </div>

                <div class="spacer2">
                </div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td style="width: 970px;" valign="top">

                            <div class="pagecontent">


    <div style="padding: 5px;">
        <div id="ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummary" class="message alert" style="color:Red;display:none;">

</div><div id="ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummarySubLayout" class="message alert" style="color:Red;display:none;">

</div>        


            <div class="report-criteria-explanation">
                Quantity returned to Inventory greater than 0, and<br>Inventory returned date is on or after the start of last month, and<br>Inventory returned date is on or before the end of last month
            </div>                                                    


        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="ButtonPanel left"><span class="button-option"><input name="ctl00$PageContent$btn1" value="Export" onclick="return false;" id="ctl00_PageContent_btn1" type="submit"><a class="dropdown" onclick="return clickreturnvalue();" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, 'ctl00_PageContent_btn1_Options', -100)"><span> </span></a><div style="visibility: hidden; left: 10px; top: 280px;" id="ctl00_PageContent_btn1_Options" class="anylinkcss"><div><a onclick="return exporter.generate('csv');" id="ctl00_PageContent_btn1_Option1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageContent$btn1_Option1','')">CSV</a></div><div><a onclick="return exporter.generate('xml');" id="ctl00_PageContent_btn1_Option2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageContent$btn1_Option2','')">XML</a></div></div></span><span>&nbsp;</span><input name="ctl00$PageContent$btn2" value="Print" onclick="window.print(); return false;" id="ctl00_PageContent_btn2" class="button" type="submit"></div>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <div class="ButtonPanel"><input name="ctl00$PageContent$btnShowCriteria" value="Show Criteria" onclick="return showCriteria('ctl00_PageContent_btnShowCriteria');" id="ctl00_PageContent_btnShowCriteria" class="wide-button" type="submit"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <div id="report-criteria-container" class="no-print" style="display: none; ">
            <table class="report-designer step3" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="report-content"><div id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl06" class="report-criteria"></div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div class="ButtonPanel"><input name="ctl00$PageContent$btn0" value="Refresh" onclick="return designer.refreshView();" id="ctl00_PageContent_btn0" class="button" type="submit"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="spacer">

</div><table class="HtmlGrid" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr class="HtmlGridHeadingRow"><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Job No.</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Description</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Project Manager</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Date</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Supplier</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Name</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Description</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Code</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell" align="right">Cost</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell" align="right">Quantity</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell" align="right">Quantity returned to Inventory</td><td class="HtmlGridHeadingCell">Inventory returned date</td></tr><tr><td class="HtmlGridCell"><a class="link" href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/jobview.aspx?id=1234567">J000123</a></td><td class="HtmlGridCell">
<br>engineering work &amp; ACME 4 &amp; 7.</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">John Doe</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">18-Dec-2013</td><td class="HtmlGridCell"><a class="link" href="https://my.workflowmax.com/client/supplierview.aspx?id=12345">Engineering Products </a></td><td class="HtmlGridCell">Upgrade</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">INSTRUMENT</td><td class="HtmlGridCell"> </td><td class="HtmlGridCell" align="right">124.00</td><td class="HtmlGridCell" align="right">1.00</td><td class="HtmlGridCell" align="right">1</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">29-Jan-2014</td></tr><tr><td class="HtmlGridCell"><a class="link" href="https://my.workflowmax.com/job/jobview.aspx?id=1234567">J000123</a></td><td class="HtmlGridCell">supply new outlet to silo 1-5 &amp; ACME 4 &amp; 7.</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">John Doe2</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">23-Jan-2014</td><td class="HtmlGridCell"><a class="link" href="https://my.workflowmax.com/client/supplierview.aspx?id=44609"></a></td><td class="HtmlGridCell">Upgrade</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">1" Automatic Butterfly</td><td class="HtmlGridCell"> </td><td class="HtmlGridCell" align="right">856.42</td><td class="HtmlGridCell" align="right">1.00</td><td class="HtmlGridCell" align="right">1</td><td class="HtmlGridCell">28-Jan-2014</td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td class="FinancialGridTotalCell">980.42</td><td> </td><td class="FinancialGridTotalCell">2</td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">    

    var exporter = new WorkflowMax.Control.ReportExport(31321321);


    var designer = new WorkflowMax.Control.ReportDesigner(16323432);    


    function showCriteria(button)
    {        
        if (Element.visible('report-criteria-container'))
        {
            Element.hide('report-criteria-container');
            $(button).value = "Show Criteria";
        }
        else
        {
            Element.show('report-criteria-container');
            designer.loadEditableCriteria('ctl00_PageContent_ctl06');    
            $(button).value = "Hide Criteria";
        }
        return false;
    }


</script>


                            </div>
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <div class="spacer">
                </div>

                <div id="footer">
                    <a href="https://my.workflowmax.com/legal/legalstuff.aspx">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>                
                </div> 

                <div id="auto_complete" class="autocomplete" style="z-index: 999; display: none;"></div>               
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_ValidationSummaries =  new Array(document.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummary"), document.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummarySubLayout"));
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummary = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummary"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummary");
ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummary.displaymode = "List";
var ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummarySubLayout = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummarySubLayout"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummarySubLayout");
ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummarySubLayout.displaymode = "List";
ctl00_PageContent_LayoutValidationSummarySubLayout.validationGroup = "SubLayout";
//]]>
</script>

<div>

    <input name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBwL+raDdrdtpAgsCgLQjP/EDgLQjIPFDgKZoKWsCgjhgjhgKmuseGAwKZoJ2sCuT5ooWx0znUqVcCNab" type="hidden"
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
WorkflowMax.Tooltip.init();//]]>
</script>
</form>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="WorkflowMax%20_%20Inventory%20Report_files/workflowmax_002.js"></script>



</body></html>
```

Comment: Not enough detail to suggest options - really depends on exactly how the reports are downloaded.

Comment: What sort of details do you need?

Comment: A URL or all of the relevant page source HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to fire a click event:

```
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00$PageContent$btn1_Option1").click()
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00$PageContent$btn1_Option1").FireEvent("onclick")
```

Comment: Do it insert this into the html?

Comment: No, It will just click on the button.